# Dart - Convert "a:3{i:0;i:105;...}" string to dart list

Tags: dart

Any ideas how to turn this string into a dart list?

"a:12{i:0;i:108;i:1;i:109;i:2;i:6;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:103;i:5;i:121;i:6;i:143;i:7;i:127;i:8;i:140;i:9;i:126;i:10;i:149;i:11;i:162;}"

Comment: What do you want the elements of the list to be?

Comment: final smallList = ["a:12{i:0;i:108;i:1;i:109;i:2;i:6;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:103;i:5;i:121;i:6;i:143;i:7;i:127;i:8;i:140;i:9;i:126;i:10;i:149;i:11;i:162;}"]; // perhaps?

Comment: I would prefer to extract the data and the final result be [108,109,6,3,103...]. I do not need the list size (a:12) or the postion i:0...)

Answer (score 0):

We can't guess the meaning of the contents of the string without some context.

From your comment, I'm guessing this is some weird encoding of an array of length 12 (`a:12{...}`) where the elements are represented as pairs of integer index (`i:0`) and integer value (`i:108`).

If that's the case, and that's *all* the content can be, then:

```dart
var _pairRE = RegExp(r"i:\d+;i:(\d+)");
var input = "a:12{i:0;i:108;i:1;i:109;i:2;i:6;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:103;i:5;i:121;i:6;i:143;i:7;i:127;i:8;i:140;i:9;i:126;i:10;i:149;i:11;i:162;}";
var output = _pairRE.allMatches(input).map((m) => int.parse(m[1]!)).toList();
```

In reality, this looks like a complicated format that can contain nested strings or arrays, just not integers (otherwise the type prefix is unnecessary), so you probably want to find a proper parser for the format.

Comment: This works. The data will be in this format for most of the cases. I can always switch up the expression in the future. Thank you!